# Google Compute Engine: startup-script is not running in Container-optimized OS

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I've been using `startup-script` metadata many times with GCE, but not with containers.

I'm trying to deploy a GCR image to a compute instance.

Instance created with this command:

```
gcloud compute instances create my-instance --image-project=cos-cloud --image-family=cos-77-lts --machine-type=e2-micro --zone=us-central1-a --metadata=GCR_ADDRESS=$GCR_ADDRESS --metadata-from-file=startup-script=./start.sh --tags=http-server,https-server
```

The `start.sh` script contains this:

```
#!/bin/bash

METADATA=http://metadata.google.internal/computeMetadata/v1
SVC_ACCT=$METADATA/instance/service-accounts/default
ACCESS_TOKEN=$(curl -H 'Metadata-Flavor: Google' $SVC_ACCT/token | cut -d'"' -f 4)
docker login -u oauth2accesstoken -p $ACCESS_TOKEN https://gcr.io

GCR_ADDRESS=$(curl "http://metadata.google.internal/computeMetadata/v1/instance/attributes/GCR_ADDRESS" -H "Metadata-Flavor: Google")

wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jfrazelle/dotfiles/master/etc/docker/seccomp/chrome.json
docker run -it --rm --security-opt seccomp=./seccomp.json $GCR_ADDRESS
```

The problem is that `startup-script` doesn't get started.

I can SSH into this instance and run the `start.sh` script manually. It works fine, pulls the image, starts the container etc.

Cloud Logger shows no traces of the `startup-script` running.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Connect to the serial port and review the boot logs. Startup script processing is logged in the boot logs. I do not remember if `journalctl` is present in COS, but if it is you can look at the boot logs from an SSH session.

Comment: thanks @JohnHanley! That helped! some of my commands required writing to fs, which is disallowed in container-optimized os. Logs indicated that. Though why the startup-script logs were present in `journalctl` but  not in Cloud Logging?

Comment: I suppose you have this issues because [COS](https://cloud.google.com/container-optimized-os/docs/concepts/features-and-benefits) is pre-configured OS with some limitations. Have you fixed your startup-script?

Comment: COS is locked down. COS cannot be modified by startup scripts. If you try, your scripts will fail.

Answer (score 0):

As per the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/container/node-pools/create#--metadata) startup-script is a reserved key used by Kubernetes Engine. At the moment, it's not possible to use startup-script script for GKE with COS. However, there is a [PIT](https://issuetracker.google.com/173057125) as a Feature Request on this issue. Feel free to post there should you have any additional comments or concerns regarding the issue.